# angular form never seems to be valid, but never gives any validation error

Tags: angular

I have been following a tutorial that consists of an angluar registration form that posts to a .net core api. I have tested the .net core api and that is working form. But my angular form for some reason never seems to validate. And when I bypass the validation the values passed to the API are always blank.

My html form is

```
<style type="text/css">
div.form-group.required>label:first-child:after {
    content:"*";
    padding-left:5px;
    color:red;
}
</style>

<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
<h1>User registration</h1>
<p>user registration <strong>with some</strong> strong txt (ctrl shift p)(wrap with abbriev) hit enter type strong hit enter</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
<form [formGroup]="service.formModel" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <!-- copy form-group div and press alt shift and either up or down arrow -->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="">Username</label>
    <input class="form-control" formConntrolName="UserName">
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.get('UserName').touched && service.formModel.get('UserName').errors?.required">This is a required field</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" formConntrolName="Email">
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.get('Email').touched && service.formModel.get('Email').errors?.required">This is a required field</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">FullName</label>
    <input class="form-control" formConntrolName="FullName">
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.get('FullName').touched && service.formModel.get('FullName').errors?.required">This is a required field</label>

</div>
<div formGroupName="Passwords">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" formConntrolName="Password">
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.get('Passwords.Password').touched && service.formModel.get('Passwords.Password').errors?.required">This is a required field</label>
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.get('Passwords.Password').touched && service.formModel.get('Passwords.Password').errors?.minlength">min 8 characters</label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">ConfirmPassword</label>
    <input class="form-control" formConntrolName="ConfirmPassword">
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').touched && service.formModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').errors?.required">This field is mandatory.</label>
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').touched && service.formModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').errors?.passwordMismatch">Confirm Password does not match.</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" [disabled]="!service.formModel.valid">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

    </div>
</div>
```

and my ts code is

```
import { UserService } from './../../shared/user.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.formModel.reset();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('frm val: ' + this.service.formModel.value.UserName);
    this.service.register().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
    if (res.succeeded) {
      this.service.formModel.reset();
      console.log('New user created! Registration successful.')
    } else {
      res.errors.forEach(element => {
        switch (element.code) {
          case 'DuplicateUserName':
        //console.log('Username is already taken','Registration failed.');
        break;

          default:
          console.log(element.description + ' Registration failed.');
        break;
        }
      });
    }
      },
      err => {
    console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

and finally my user.service.ts code is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
//import { variable } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private http:HttpClient) { }
  readonly BaseUri = 'http://localhost:52044/api';

  formModel = this.fb.group({
    UserName : ['',Validators.required],
    Email : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.email]],
    FullName : ['',Validators.required],
    Passwords : this.fb.group({
      Password : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)]],
      ConfirmPassword : ['',Validators.required]
    },{validator: this.comparePasswords})
  });

 comparePasswords(fb: FormGroup) {
  let confirmPswrdCtrl = fb.get('ConfirmPassword');
console.log('psws: ' + fb.get('Password').value);
  if (confirmPswrdCtrl.errors == null || 'passwordMismatch' in confirmPswrdCtrl.errors) {
    if (fb.get('Password').value != confirmPswrdCtrl.value)
      confirmPswrdCtrl.setErrors({ passwordMismatch: true });
    else
      confirmPswrdCtrl.setErrors(null);
  }
}

  register() {
    // to change both instances of something eg the word FullName highlight the first and press
    //ctrl and d then when you change one instance it will change both
    var body = {
      UserName: this.formModel.value.UserName,
      Email: this.formModel.value.Email,
      FullName: this.formModel.value.FullName,
      Password: this.formModel.value.Passwords.Password
    }
    // var body = {
    //   UserName: 'usernametest',
    //   Email: 'username@blar.com',
    //   FullName: 'blar di blar',
    //   Password: 'abc1234'
    // }
    console.log('username : ' + this.formModel.value.UserName);
    return this.http.post(this.BaseUri + '/applicationuser/register', body);
  }
}
```

when I inspect the username element in the browser this is what is there

```
<div _ngcontent-gtd-c1="" class="form-group required">
    <label _ngcontent-gtd-c1="" for="">Username</label>
    <input _ngcontent-gtd-c1="" class="form-control" formconntrolname="UserName">
    <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }-->
</div>
```

is the "bindings={" bit correct?

Can anyone shed any light on what is going wrong and secondly give me some advice on how I can debug it my self?

Thanks

Comment: It's not `(submit)`, but `(ngSubmit)`. It's not `formConntrolName`, but `formControlName`. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: OMG, I have been trying to fix this for a week. School boy error. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this for validation :

```
<label *ngIf="service.formModel.hasError('required', 'UserName')">
          UserName required.
        </label>
```